# Holomorph of a group $G$, then the automorphism of $G$ are inner automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product, automorphism-group, holomorph

In my course notes of algebra it says:

> Let $G$ be a group. Then $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ acts on $G$ in a natural way through automorphisms. This allows us to consider $A:= G \rtimes \mathrm{Aut}(G)$. *In this group every automorphism of $G$ is an inner automorphism.* This group is called the holomorph of $G$.

I don't understand the statement concerning the inner automorphisms.

The first part means $G\rtimes \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ being a group with group operation
$$
 (g,\theta) \cdot (h,\psi) = (gh^{\theta^{-1}}, \theta \psi)
$$
right?

And an automorphism $\phi$ on a group $G$ is an inner automorphism if $g^\phi = h^{-1}gh$ for a certain $h\in G$.

I would think the last statement means something like: For any $\phi\in \mathrm{Aut}(G)$
$$
 (g,\theta)^\phi = (h,\psi)^{-1} (g,\theta) (h,\psi) \qquad \text{for a certain } (h,\psi) \in A 
$$

But this doesn't make any sense, since $(g,\theta)^\phi$ is not even defined. Can someone help me make sense of this last statement?

Comment: I added the "group-theory" tag to your post.  Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The precise wording would be that 'every automorphism of $G$ *extends to* an inner automorphism of $A$'.

Namely, conjugation by $(1,\theta)$ restricted to $G\subseteq A$ will give back just $\theta\in Aut(G)$.